Non-uniqueness for Fourier Interpolation
I am working through a past exam and I am asked to show that under certain conditions, Fourier interpolation with basis function $e^{inx}, n=0, \ldots N-1$ is unique and to provide an example where it is non-unique.
I am able to show it is unique when there are $N$ points $(x_j, y_j)_{j=0}^{N-1}$. In this case, if we define
$$l_m(e^{ix})=\prod_{j=0, j\neq m}^{N-1} \frac{e^{ix} - e^{ix_j}}{e^{ix_m} - e^{ix_j} },$$
then
$$\Pi_N(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{N-1} y_k \,l_k(e^{ix})$$
satisfies
$$\Pi_N(x_l)=y_l, \quad 0\le l\le N-1.$$
Furthermore, if $\Pi'_N$ is another such polynomial, then
$\Pi_N-\Pi'_N$ is a polynomial of order $N-1$ in $z=e^{ix}$ that vanishes at $N$ points, hence must be identically zero.
For non-uniqueness, I took $M$ points, $(x_l, y_l)$, $N$ exponents $m_j\in \mathbb{N}$, and considered the system
$$P(x_l)=\sum_{j=0}^{N-1} \alpha_j z^{m_j}_l=y_j, \quad 0\le l \le M-1, z_l = e^{ix_l}$$
for the coefficients $\alpha_j$ of $P$ of order $\max_{0\le j\le N-1} m_j$. We can write this as a matrix equation
$$B\alpha=y\quad, B_{lj} =z^{m_j}_l \in \mathbb{C}^{M\times N}, \alpha\in \mathbb{C}^N, y\in \mathbb{C}^M.$$
If $N>M$, the system is undetermined and uniqueness fails. To be specific, we can pick $N=10, m_j=j^2, 1\le j\le 10, M=5, (x_l, y_l)=(2l+1, l^2), 1\le l\le 5$. Is this a suitable example?

Your proofs are correct. I do not quite get your example, as no specific polynomials are present.  The proof of the uniqueness suggests the following general example. $$\widetilde{\Pi}_N(x)=\Pi_N(x)+\prod_{j=0}^{N-1}(e^{ix}-e^{ix_j})$$ Then $\deg\widetilde{\Pi}_N=N$ and $\widetilde{\Pi}_N(x_j)=\Pi_N(x_j)$ for $0\le j\le N-1.$
